# Binding a custom catalog-add-to-cart.js to a custom add to cart button?

Tags: magento2, javascript, addtocart

Magento 2.4.6

I added another add to cart button to the product page in `addtocart.phtml`:

```
<button type="submit"
                title="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $buttonSampleTitle ?>"
                class="action primary sample tocart"
                id="product-sample-button">
            <span><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $buttonSampleTitle ?></span>
        </button>
```

Now, when I click it, code in `catalog-add-to-cart.js` is triggered because of the `tocart` class on the button.

How can I register another JS file (not catalog-add-to-cart.js) that handles what happens when the button is clicked? I guess the first step would be to remove the `tocart` class, but whats next?

Thanks!